# How set breakpoint to class member variable in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, breakpoints, watchpoint

How can I set breakpoint (or watchpoint) to member variable in class for all instances of this class?

I have tried set breakpoint on line in class with this member variable but this is not working.

Comment: try to grep source code for all occurrences of your variable, set breakpoints everywere where it is modified line by line.

Comment: I cannot set breakpoint on getter and setter in header.

Comment: Do you have implementations of your getter/setter in header? What gdb command do you use? Do you compile with -g option?

Comment: Implementations of getter and setter are in header. It is possible to add breakpoint in cpp file. I use "breakpoint <line>".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set breakpoint to the setter and getter function as shown below

```
break TestClass::setVal(int)
break TestClass::getVal()
```

Note that, we have to specify the type of arguments that the function is receiving.

Find more details [here](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbbreak.html)